# Как перевести большой android проект на чистую архитектуру?

Tags: android, архитектура, миграция

На данный момент у меня есть проект, в котором о слове "архитектура" никто не слышал, вероятно, с момента его начала. Мне очень бы хотелось услышать ваши советы о том, как осуществлять постепенный переход с отсутствия архитектуры на ее положительное присутствие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переходить, как вы сами написали, постепенно.

Для начала примените к методам классов принцип единственной ответственности.
Потом поднимитесь на уровень выше и примените его-же к классам. Это даст свободу маневра.

После этого можно браться за остальные принципы SOLID. Я бы в целом придерживался следующей последовательности:

L - Принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков

D - Принцип инверсии зависимостей

I - Принцип разделения интерфейса

O - Принцип открытости/закрытости

Ну и, конечно, помним про правило бойскаута

> Хорошо написать код недостаточно. Необходимо
>   поддерживать чистоту кода с течением времени. Все мы видели, как код
>   загнивает и деградирует с течением времени. Значит, мы должны активно
>   поработать над тем, чтобы этого не произошло. У бойскаутов существует
>   простое правило, которое применимо и к нашей профессии: Оставь место
>   стоянки чище, чем оно было до твоего прихода. Если мы все будем
>   оставлять свой код чище, чем он был до нашего прихода, то код попросту
>   не будет загнивать. Чистка не обязана быть глобальной. Присвойте более
>   понятное имя переменной, разбейте слишком большую функцию, устраните
>   одно незначительное повторение, упростите сложную цепочку условий.
>   Представляете себе работу над проектом, код которого улучшается с
>   течением времени? Но может ли профессионал позволить себе нечто иное?
>   Разве постоянное совершенствование не является неотъемлемой частью
>   профессионализма?

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Я на днях закончил переписывать свой проект (6 экранов, база данных, http запросы, rxjava с [использованием Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html)). На все ушло 3 с половиной недели.

Начать я думаю стоит с изучения этой самой чистой архитектуры, после выделить на это время и собственно взяться за рефакторинг.

Вот последнее видео которое по моему мнению самое интересное с точки зрения архитектуры.
https://academy.realm.io/posts/converting-an-app-to-use-clean-architecture/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне кажется, что вы не совсем поняли вопрос. Основная проблема заключается не в моем непонимании CA, а в том, что у меня есть большой проект без этой самой CA. И суть именно в способах, которыми можно не-особенно-болезненно перевести страх и ужас в нормальное состояния параллельно с доработками/правками.

Comment: Тогда я бы наверное выделил какой-то участок и начал рефакторить его. Например самым простым будет начать с экрана "логин" если такой имеется. Ну и следовать первому ответу.